# why my navigation bar wont show background color

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm trying to make a sample website about photography, and as I start with my navigation bar, I have come to the issues of the background color not working. I have tried many things like putting an Id to call my nav on my CSS file. I have also tried using div, nav or even using a class and it won't work. I am sorry if this might be an easy fix but I am new to this.

```css
body , html {
    background-color: #F7FDFF;

}
div {
    background-color: #000;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none; 

}
li a {
    display: block; 
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none; 
    float: right; 
    text-align: right;
    color: black; 
    padding: 1.5em; 
}

li a:hover{
    display: block;
    background-color: #B5B5B5;
    color: #000; 

}
.active {
    background-color: green; 
}
#navbar {
    background-color: rgb(18, 171, 209); 
}
```

```html
<div>
    <nav id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your anchor tags are floated and there are no other non floated elements, your nav element collapsed. To fix these follow below steps.

1. Create a clearfix class like this. It will stop your nav element from collapsing.

   `.clearfix::after { 
       content: " ";
       display: block;
       height: 0;
       clear: both;
   }`

and add this class to your nav element

2. Remove the `float: right;` rule from your anchor element, aka from `ul li a` selector. Right now, because of this rule, your last element becomes the first menu, aka "Contact" became first menu and "Home" became last. To understand why this happend [read this](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).
3. Add a new rule `float: left;` for your `li` element. If you don't add this rule, your li elements each will take a seperate line, because by default li elements are block level elements. To keep them in the same line you have to add this rule. You can also add `display: inline-block` to change its default display property from block to inline to keep them in the same line. But there is a small problem with this solution, you will notice a small gap between inline-block elements. If those small gaps are not a problem for your design then go ahead and use `display: block;` rule, otherwise use `float: left;`. (To understand the difference hover over the menu next to the active menu)
4. Add two more rules `float: right;` and `margin: 0;` for your `ul` element. This will move your menu to the right as you intended. `margin: 0;` is there to remove the extra margins. You can change/delete this rule as per your design.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <link href="Css/Stylesheets.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset= utf-8> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width= device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>LTphotography</title>
</head>
<style>
body , html {
    background-color: #F7FDFF;

}
div {
    background-color: #000;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none; 
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block; 
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: right;
    color: black; 
    padding: 1.5em; 
}

li a:hover{
    display: block;
    background-color: #B5B5B5;
    color: #000; 

}
.active {
    background-color: green; 
}
#navbar {
    background-color: rgb(18, 171, 209); 
}

.clearfix::after { 
    content: " ";
    display: block; 
    height: 0; 
    clear: both;
}
</style>`
<body>
    <div>
        <nav id="navbar" class="clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your containing li's are collapsing because they contain floated content. You need to add a clearfix to your `li` items.

```
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

<ul>
 <li class="clearfix"></li>
 // and so on
</ul>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp

That said, you can also simply remove `float: right` from your anchor elements. It shouldn't be necessary.